# Monotone sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\epsilon>0$. We define the sequence of function
$
H_{n}(s)=n^{\epsilon}+\epsilon n^{\epsilon+1}(\frac{1}{n}-s)
$ if $0<s\leq\frac{1}{n}$ and $H_{n}(s)=s^{-\epsilon}$ if $s>\frac{1}{n}$. 
I have checked the above sequence converges pointwise to $s^{-\epsilon}$ as $n\to\infty$. I want to verify if the above convergence is monotone. Can somebody please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have a bad trick to solve this problem. Fix $0<s\leq\frac{1}{n}$. Please take the derivative of the function with respect to $n$. The derivative of the first segment is:

$$ \epsilon n^{\epsilon-1}(1+ (1+\epsilon)(1-ns))$$. Note that $(1-ns)$ is definitely nonnegative. Also, the derivative of the second piece of the function is always zero. Since the derivative is non-negative, the sequence of function is monotone (ie monotone w/r $n$).

Computation: $H_{n+1}(s) -H_n(s)$= $$ ((n+1)^{\epsilon}- (n)^{\epsilon}) +\epsilon(n+1)^{\epsilon}(1-(n+1)s) - \epsilon(n)^{\epsilon}(1-ns)$$
$$\leq ((n+1)^{\epsilon}- (n)^{\epsilon}) +\epsilon(n+1)^{\epsilon}(1-(n)s) - \epsilon(n)^{\epsilon}(1-ns)$$
$$=((n+1)^{\epsilon}- (n)^{\epsilon}) +\epsilon(n+1)^{\epsilon}(1-ns) - \epsilon(n)^{\epsilon}(1-ns)$$

$$=[(n+1)^{\epsilon}- (n)^{\epsilon}] +[(n+1)^{\epsilon} - (n)^{\epsilon}](1-ns)\epsilon$$
$$=[(n+1)^{\epsilon}- (n)^{\epsilon}][1+(1-ns)\epsilon]$$, which is non-negative. This proves that the sequence is actaully a monontone.

Comment: I am little confused with the argument. For every fixed $s$ we need to prove $H_{n+1}(s)\geq H_n(s)$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $0<s\leq\frac{1}{n+1}$ then by definition $H_{n+1}(s)=(n+1)^{\epsilon}+\epsilon (n+1)^{\epsilon+1}(\frac{1}{(n+1)}-s)$ which should be bigger than $H_{n}(s)=n^{\epsilon}+\epsilon n^{\epsilon+1}(\frac{1}{n}-s)$ since $0<s\leq\frac{1}{n+1}$ implies $0<s\leq\frac{1}{n}$. And the same thing has to be true for $s>\frac{1}{n}$. While calculating I got stuck to get such inequality. Can you help me please. Thanks.

Comment: Derivative non-negative means what?

Comment: Okay, I am showing the equality directly.

Comment: @Mathlover please have a look at the edited version. Thank you.

Comment: Please have a look at the function carefully. It is truncated. First the above calculation is correct, but the rhs is nonnegative does not imply monotone, that only gives $H_{n+1}(s)\leq H_n(s)+K$ where $K$ is some nonnegative quantity. @MMM

Comment: Sorry, I obtained the wrong equality. I'll correct my inequality again. Thanks.